# Python image processing - noise removal

Tags: python, opencv, image-processing

I'm trying to de-noise an image which looks like this:

[image]

How can the white noisy pixels be removed? Initially I thought a median filter should suffice, but it doesn't look like it. Moreover, the image is RGB. Any thoughts?

I use Python.

(img: https://www.dropbox.com/s/aiyxkswtiyji7cw/exampledenoise.png?dl=0)

Comment: how did that picture happen? that almost looks like black _wrapped around_... you gotta explain what happened there. there is no good way to *repair* this. it has to be prevented.

Comment: I'm trying to gather images for vehicle detection, in various conditions. This is one among them.

Comment: well, from the PNG, I managed to null all those defects and (none of the headlights!) with a median blur, some thresholding, and some boolean operations. that probably depended a lot on some specific parameters though. I'd discard such pictures or investigate what broke to cause this.

Comment: To me it looks like the image was processed in some way, there is no way that a camera would output something like this.

Answer (score 3):

Median blur, thresholding, comparisons, boolean expressions.

Unless you know why this picture was damaged and *how*, this is just guesswork.

In the PNG the defects all have an exact value of 255. Defects happen in dark areas of the picture. I'm guessing that something caused an underflow in those pixels, wrapping them from 0 or -1 to 255.

```py
# using my own "imshow" shim for jupyter notebook, which handles boolean arrays

im = cv.imread("exampledenoise.png")

# imshow((im == 255).any(axis=2))
```

[image: im == 255]

```
# estimating local brightness... so we DON'T "fix" bright spots
ksize = 13 # least value that appears to suppress all defects
med = cv.medianBlur(im, ksize=ksize)
# imshow(med)
```

[image: med]

```
# imshow(med >= 64) # candidate areas/channels.
# true = values likely explained by overexposure (don't fix)
# false = values likely explained by defect
```

[image: med >= 64]

```
fixup = (med < 64) & (im == 255)
assert len(fixup.shape) == 3 # fix individual channels
# imshow(fixup.any(axis=2)) # gonna fix values in these pixels
```

[image: fixup]

```
output = im.copy()
output[fixup] = 0 # assuming the damage was from some underflow, so 0 is appropriate
# imshow(output)
```

[image: output]